# Subscription Products are Non-restoring, Why Apple is asking me to put up a restore button?

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval

I don't understand Apple Guidelines. I had created an app which is having free as well as premium features.

By default the app comes installed with free features, I had provided the buy button so that user can buy the premium features of the app using the in-app purchase feature.

The duration of subscription is 3-Months and it is non-renewing.

I submitted the app to App store, but apple is asking me to place a restore button in the app, so that users can restore their previous purchases.

on the other hand, It is written in the apple documentation that you cannot restore subscription based apps.

It seems quite confusing to me, Can you please guide what to do in this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1) You don't know that some of your purchases are restorable.

2) Apple doesn't know that all of your purchases are non-restorable.

Follow up with Apple.

**EDIT** The above is wrong.  You need to restore the purchases *on your own* without their support, since you chose to not use auto renewing.  From [the IAP guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/APIOverview/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html)

> You are required to deliver non-renewing subscriptions to all devices owned by the user. Non-renewing subscriptions are not automatically synchronized to all devices by Store Kit; you must implement this infrastructure yourself. For example, most subscriptions are provided by an external server; your server would need to implement a mechanism to identify users and associate subscription purchases with the user who purchased them.

Comment: How I can find out whether my purchases are restorable or not ?